# Winsock error 10038 starting from third connection

Tags: c, windows, sockets, localhost

I need to send from a TCP server simple data to multiple clients connected in loop back.
The send command has success for the first two clients but it fails with error 10038 when I try to connect with a third client.

The code is very simple, on the first connection a thread is created, then for the other connections the opened socket is added to a global array.
The thread sends the same data (the string "hello") to all clients connected (via localhost).

Did I make a trivial bug? Is there something I don't know? Why it works only with two connections?

EDIT:

I want to underline that the code I posted is only an example and it is not written to be a real server, it wants only to show a strange symptom that I don't understand, I mean, why when the third client connect to server the send fails with error 10038 (WSAENOTSOCK)?

What happens in my test (on the same machine) is:

1. I run the server
2. I open a telnet connection on port 5000, it
       shows an infinite loop with "Hello", and this is what I expected.
3. I open a second telnet connection on port 5000, it shows an infinite
       loop with "Hello", and this is what I expected.
4. I open a third
       telnet connection on port 5000, the connection fails quite
       immediately and the server says "error 10038" on the third socket.

Why the third connection fails? What am I doing wrong?

**My code:**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>

int nclients = 0;
SOCKET  lClient[10];
CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;

DWORD WINAPI ClientThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int          i;

    char buffer[20] = "Hello\n";

    while(1) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
        for (i=0;i<nclients;i++) {
            if (lClient[i] != INVALID_SOCKET) {
                if( send(lClient[i], buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0) < 0) {
                    printf("socket() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    nclients--;
                }
            }
        }
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
        Sleep(200); 
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    WSADATA             wsd;
    SOCKET              sListen, sClient;
    int                 iAddrSize;
    HANDLE              hThread;
    DWORD               dwThreadId;
    struct sockaddr_in  local, client;
    int i,iPort;

    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) lClient[i] = INVALID_SOCKET;

    iPort = 5000;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsd) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to load Winsock!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Create our listening socket
    //
    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sListen == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("socket() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    // Select the local interface and bind to it
    //
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(iPort);

    if (bind(sListen, (struct sockaddr *)&local,
        sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    listen(sListen, 8);
    //
    // In a continous loop, wait for incoming clients. Once one
    // is detected, create a thread and pass the handle off to it.
    //
    while (1)
    {
        iAddrSize = sizeof(client);
        sClient = accept(sListen, (struct sockaddr *)&client,&iAddrSize);
        if (sClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("accept() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
        printf("Accepted client: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));
        if (nclients == 0) {
            hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ClientThread, 0, 0, &dwThreadId);
            EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
            lClient[nclients] = sClient;
            nclients++;
            LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
        }
        else {
            EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
            lClient[nclients] = sClient;
            nclients++;
            LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
        }
        if (hThread == NULL)
        {
            printf("CreateThread() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    closesocket(sListen);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking up what Winsock error 10038 means?

Comment: I would use a pool of threads, with a new connection being directed to the next available thread.  When a thread completes, it is returned to the pool rather than killing it.  This saves massive amounts of time because threads do not have to be repeatedly created/destroyed.  you might want to look at: http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.c.php and http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/C++-report-col6.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your thread loop is not updating the array correctly when it encounters an error.  And your main code is not handling the possibility of all clients disconnecting and then a new client connects, so it is potentially creating multiple threads.

Try this instead:

```
bool keepRunning = true;

DWORD WINAPI ClientThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    const char buffer[] = "Hello\n";
    const int buflen = strlen(buffer) ;

    while (keepRunning)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);

        int i = 0;
        while ((i < nclients) && (keepRunning))
        {
            if (send(lClient[i], buffer, buflen, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                int err = WSAGetLastError();
                closesocket(lClient[i]);

                if (err != WSAENOTSOCK)
                    printf("Failed to send data to a client! Error: %d\n", err);

                for (int j = i+1; j < nclients; ++j)
                    lClient[j-1] = lClient[j];

                --nclients;
            }
            else
            {
                ++i;
            }
        }

        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);

        Sleep(200); 
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA             wsd;
    SOCKET              sListen, sClient;
    int                 iAddrSize;
    HANDLE              hThread = NULL;
    DWORD               dwThreadId = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in  local, client;
    int iPort;

    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) lClient[i] = INVALID_SOCKET;

    iPort = 5000;

    int ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsd);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to load Winsock! Error: %d\n", ret);
        return 1;
    }

    // Create our listening socket
    //
    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sListen == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Failed to create listening socket! Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Select the local interface and bind to it
    //
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(iPort);

    if (bind(sListen, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
       printf("Failed to bind listening socket! Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       closesocket(sListen);
       WSACleanup();
       return 1;
    }

    // Start listening for clients
    //
    if (listen(sListen, 8) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
       printf("Failed to listen for clients! Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       closesocket(sListen);
       WSACleanup();
       return 1;
    }

    //
    // In a continuous loop, wait for incoming clients. Once
    // one is detected, create a thread to process clients.
    //
    while (keepRunning)
    {
        iAddrSize = sizeof(client);
        sClient = accept(sListen, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &iAddrSize);
        if (sClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Unable to accept a client! Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

        EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);

        if (nclients == 10)
        {
            LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
            closesocket(sClient);

            printf("Ignoring client: %s:%d, too many clients already connected\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));

            continue;
        }

        lClient[nclients] = sClient;
        ++nclients;

        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);

        printf("Accepted client: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));

        if (!hThread)
        {
            hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ClientThread, 0, 0, &dwThreadId);
            if (hThread == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to create thread! Error: %u\n", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    keepRunning = false;

    if (hThread != NULL)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nclients; ++i)
        closesocket(lClient[i]);
    closesocket(sListen);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or, using his existing code, just set the element to `INVALID_SOCKET` and don't decrement the count.

Comment: But then dead clients would never leave the array, and new clients would eventually overflow the array since the original code was not doing any bounds checking. When a client is disconnected, it should be removed from the array. The original code was not doing that correctly (not closing dead sockets, decrementing the array counter while using it as a loop counter the wrong way, etc). So yeah, the original code was not managing the array correctly, so it very likely would encounter invalid sockets at times and fail with errors.

Comment: Well you would put a new client into an `INVALID_SOCKET` entry if there was one.